# how do I give a lengthy comment on a previous answer?

Tags: support, comment

A question was posted and answered several years ago about the "Hyperbolic diameter of Amsler's surface".  The answer points to a relevant paper and summarizes its results.  But that summary of results makes brief, strong claims -- claims that are arguably too strong.

I have read the cited paper, and I would like to post a comment that gives further details about its results.  I started to "add a comment" to the existing answer -- but comments are apparently limited in length.  So I started to type in a new answer -- but I was warned that answers should answer the question, not talk about previous answers.

What should I do?

Comment: I would write a new answer and indicate that it is meant as a comment on another answer.

Comment: Somewhat related: [This is a comment, not an answer!](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4353/this-is-a-comment-not-an-answer)

Comment: Depends on the nature of your "comment", you can start your answer with a line stating this is a "comment" or "supplement" of the other answer with a very short paragraph summarizing what it is before presenting your own arguments.

Comment: Comments are limited in length, but (continued)

Comment: (continued) you can always start one, and (continued)

Comment: (continued) when you run out of room, continue it in another. Mind you, I think the other suggestion of writing a new answer is better, I just thought I'd mention this option.

Comment: One aspect (perhaps an advantage) of posting one or more Comments on the Answer is motivating (if necessary) the supplementary reasoning, and inviting a brief response.